# why kivy gives error in starting of the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I downloaded kivy successfully.
When I was trying to start the kivy window with this command that I found at the original kivy basics web site:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

It gives an error:

```
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py in mainloop(self)
    746             try:
--> 747                 self._mainloop()
    748             except BaseException as inst:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py in _mainloop(self)
    478     def _mainloop(self):
--> 479         EventLoop.idle()
    480 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in idle(self)
    361             Logger.error('Base: Application will leave')
--> 362             self.exit()
    363             return False

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in exit(self)
    374         '''Close the main loop and close the window.'''
--> 375         self.close()
    376         if self.window:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in close(self)
    171         self.quit = True
--> 172         self.stop()
    173         self.status = 'closed'

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in stop(self)
    183         for provider in reversed(self.input_providers[:]):
--> 184             provider.stop()
    185             if provider in self.input_providers_autoremove:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_pen.py in stop(self)
    110             self.pen = None
--> 111             SetWindowLong_WndProc_wrapper(self.hwnd, self.old_windProc)
    112 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_common.py in _closure(hWnd, wndProc)
    121         def _closure(hWnd, wndProc):
--> 122             oldAddr = func(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, cast(wndProc, c_void_p).value)
    123             return cast(c_void_p(oldAddr), WNDPROC)

ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in runTouchApp(widget, slave)
    503         else: 
--> 504             EventLoop.window.mainloop()
    505     finally:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py in mainloop(self)
    751
```

Please help me why doesn't it works?
Here is the example of working: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html

Comment: Can you add how you started your example and which libraries you installed?

Comment: I also ran into some trouble when installing kivy. The installation process was ok (it did not give me any error), but it was not working. Check  this question and the procedure on the answer to see if this solves your problem: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460216/error-core-option-mode-not-recognized-importing-kivy-on-pycharm/58031740#58031740>